# Function with same name as struct

Tags: initialization, rust

In general, I prefer to write initializer functions with descriptive names. However, for some structs, there is an obvious default initializer function. The standard Rust name for such a function is `new`, placed in the `impl` block for the struct. However, today I realized that I can give a function the same name as a struct, and thought this would be a good way to implement the obvious initializer function. For example:

```
#[derive(Debug, Clone, Copy)]
struct Pair<T, U> {
    first: T,
    second: U,
}

#[allow(non_snake_case)]
fn Pair<T, U>(first: T, second: U) -> Pair<T, U> {
    Pair::<T, U> {
        first: first,
        second: second,
    }
}

fn main(){
    let x = Pair(1, 2);
    println!("{:?}", x);
}
```

This is, in my opinion, much more appealing than this:

```
let x = Pair::new(1, 2);
```

However, I've never seen anyone else do this, and my question is simply if there are any problems with this approach. Are there, for example, ambiguities which it can cause which will not be there with the `new` implementation?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to use `Pair(T, U)` then you should consider using a tuple struct instead:

```
#[derive(Debug, Clone, Copy)]
struct Pair<T, U>(T, U);

fn main(){
    let x = Pair(1, 2);
    println!("{:?}", x);
    println!("{:?}, {:?}", (x.0, x.1));
}
```

Or, y’know, just a tuple (`(T, U)`). But I presume that `Pair` is not your actual use case.

---

There was a time when having identically named functions was the convention for default constructors; this convention fell out of favour as time went by. It is considered bad form nowadays, probably mostly for consistency. If you have a tuple struct (or variant) `Pair(T, U)`, then you can use `Pair(first, last)` in a pattern, but if you have `Pair { first: T, last: U }` then you would need to use something more like `Pair { first, last }` in a pattern, and so your `Pair(first, last)` function would be inconsistent with the pattern. It is generally felt, thus, that these type of camel-case functions should be reserved solely for tuple structs and tuple variants, where it can be known that it is genuinely reflecting what is contained in the data structure with no further processing or magic.

Comment: You presume correctly. It was just the first simple example that popped into my head. Perhaps a better example would be a `Point` struct, where you want named members (x, y and z). It doesn't have to be a simple structure though. Even something like `Vec`, from the standard library, where `new` creates an empty container, would be a candidate.

Comment: @BenjaminLindley: I’ve added some more explanation explaining the whys and wherefores.